# Cascading simple derived identity in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

How can I cascade a joined model with a `OneToOne` relationship where by only the `User` table has an auto increment strategy and the joined `Profile` model must have an id that matches the `User` id.

My models look like this:

`Company\Model\User`:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var Profile
     */
    private $profile;
```

`Company\Model\Profile`:

```
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="profile")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id")
     * @var User
     */
    private $user;
```

When persisting an instance of the `User` model, it causes the following error to be output:

> Entity of type Company\Model\Profile is missing an assigned ID for field  'profile'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

The doctrine documentation calls this a simple derived identity, but does not explain how to cascade it.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is actually quite simple.

First the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` need to be swapped around.

Secondly, when setting the `Profile` on the `User` you must set the user on the profile in turn.

`Company\Model\User`:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var Profile
     */
    private $profile;

    public function setProfile(Profile $profile): void
    {
        $this->profile = $profile;
        $this->profile->setUser($this);
    }
```

`Company\Model\Profile`:

```
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id")
     * @var User
     */
    private $user;
```